# My visa letter was cancelled; is my visa still valid?

Tags: visas, schengen, invitation-letters

I applied for a German visa for a social responsibility project, and was given a multiple entry visa.  I worked on the project for 10 days but, because of conditions, I left the project and left Germany. I still have the visa but the organization that sponsored me informed the visa services that I was no longer involved. Now I want to visit my uncle in Germany. Will there any problem in passport control if I try to enter with this visa?

Comment: The quickest way would be to ask an embassy etc. ... wen can't know for sure if your visa was cancelled. ... Anyways, the text might give a hint, but we don't have that either.

Answer (score 4):

According to my understanding of [Article 34](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810), there is no reason (in practice) for cancellation of your visa. The 10-day visit proves that there is no fraud on the application. In addition, it is a multiple-entry visa, your further visits to Schengen Area don't have to be for the same purpose.

Consulates don't put 34.2 into practice for multiple-entry visas in most cases. The "conditions" in that paragraph are not just related to the changes on travel dates or visit durations. Unless the change affects competent authorities' trust on you, they don't cancel your visa.

Since the final decision depends on the officer, I recommend to send an e-mail to the consulate anyway. It's a good idea to mention the visa application number in the e-mail.

> *Article 34*
>
> **Annulment and revocation**
>
> 1. A visa shall be annulled where it becomes evident that the conditions for issuing it were not met at the time when it was issued,
>      in particular if there are serious grounds for believing that the visa
>      was fraudulently obtained. A visa shall in principle be annulled by
>      the competent authorities of the Member State which issued it. A visa
>      may be annulled by the competent authorities of another Member State,
>      in which case the authorities of the Member State that issued the visa
>      shall be informed of such annulment.
> 2. A visa shall be revoked where it becomes evident that the conditions for issuing it are no longer met. A visa shall in principle
>      be revoked by the competent authorities of the Member State which
>      issued it. A visa may be revoked by the competent authorities of
>      another Member State, in which case the authorities of the Member
>      State that issued the visa shall be informed of such revocation.
> 3. A visa may be revoked at the request of the visa holder. The competent authorities of the Member States that issued the visa shall
>      be informed of such revocation.
> 4. Failure of the visa holder to produce, at the border, one or more of the supporting documents referred to in Article 14(3), shall not
>      automatically lead to a decision to annul or revoke the visa.
> 5. If a visa is annulled or revoked, a stamp stating ‘ANNULLED’ or ‘REVOKED’ shall be affixed to it and the optically variable feature of
>      the visa sticker, the security feature ‘latent image effect’ as well
>      as the term ‘visa’ shall be invalidated by being crossed out.
> 6. A decision on annulment or revocation of a visa and the reasons on which it is based shall be notified to the applicant by means of
>      the standard form set out in Annex VI.
> 7. A visa holder whose visa has been annulled or revoked shall have the right to appeal, unless the visa was revoked at his request in
>      accordance with paragraph 3. Appeals shall be conducted against the
>      Member State that has taken the decision on the annulment or
>      revocation and in accordance with the national law of that Member
>      State. Member States shall provide applicants with information
>      regarding the procedure to be followed in the event of an appeal, as
>      specified in Annex VI.
> 8. Information on an annulled or a revoked visa shall be entered into the VIS in accordance with Article 13 of the VIS Regulation.

Comment: Why do you think clause 2 doesnt apply to the OP?

Comment: @HankyPanky I've improved my answer, I hope it's sufficient.

Comment: Importantly, this article lists _who_ can request a visa to be revoked. "Competent authorities of Member States" (1/2) and "visa holder" (3). This does **not** list the sponsor.